# Can I send WhatsApp messages from my Java (or any language) applications?

Tags: java, android, api, message, whatsapp

We can send emails or SMS through our application written in Java or many languages. Is there any mechanism to send WhatsApp messages through our applications / web site?

Comment: Please help me by adding proper tags to reach this question

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can open the whatsapp chat with the given number.

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
}
```